# Please help me to understand whether VLAN will fulfill my needs

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

At my work there is a 24-port NetGear switch that supports VLANs. We need 2 physical LANs in the room. I thought, if a smart switch is there, we could split it  into two switches, 12 ports each, without a need to buy a second switch.

As far as I know, an equipment from Mikrotik allows grouping physical ports to switches without a need to reconfigure anything on connected computers.

The NetGear switch we have does not support such a feature, but supports VLANs only. Are VLANs doing the same?

The big question which bothers me is:

**If I use VLANs, do they work transparently for connected computers, or I need to reconfigure each of them for VLAN usage?**

I could not find a clear and unambiguous answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of VLANs:

- Untagged VLANs
- Tagged VLANs

Untagged VLANs are simple.  You configure them on the switch to isolate ports into their own virtual LANs.  The connected computers do not know anything about untagged VLANs, so there is no additional configuration needed on those computers.  This is like a "default" VLAN when there are no tags involved.

Tagged VLANs are for if you want to be able to access multiple VLANs from one network port.  This *does* require configuration from the connected computers because those computers decide which VLAN they want to talk to by tagging the associated Ethernet frames.

**In your case, you probably want just untagged VLANs.**  It sounds like you want two isolated networks (VLANs) that do not need to talk to other VLANs.

---

## Additional Resources

- [VLAN Basics](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/VLAN_Basics) <sup>[[archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170713025836/https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/VLAN_Basics)]</sup> on [Thomas-Krenn-Wiki](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Main_Page)
- [Why and how are Ethernet Vlans tagged?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6483) on [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on any VLAN-capable switch, you can configure any ports as "access" ports that expect to receive and transmit frames that are not VLAN-tagged ("untagged frames"), even though the switch knows which VLAN that port is associated with, and will make sure any traffic coming in that port will be kept on the same VLAN as that port.

If you have another VLAN-capable switch or a server or something that needs to be connected to more than one VLAN on the first switch, you can "trunk" those VLANs over a single Ethernet connection, by setting that port to a "trunk" port. Trunk ports are associated with multiple VLANs, and they expect all frames to be tagged with VLAN IDs (VLAN-tagged) so that the traffic for each VLAN can still be kept separate by the receiving switch or server or whatnot. If you connect a device to a trunk port, and you want that devices to access the multiple VLANs that are available on that trunk port, you will have to configure that device's VLAN support so that it knows what VLAN IDs are available on that port.

There are often ways to make ports that can handle both tagged and untagged frames. But the untagged frames can only be associated with a single VLAN.

There is sometimes proprietary terminology associated with these concepts, but all VLAN-capable switches pretty much let you do all the same things, they just may present it with slightly different terminology or UI.